# Different behaviour of returning class object from a function

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

The following code

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {a = 1;};
    Foo(const Foo&) :a(2) {};
    int a;
};

Foo foo()
{
    Foo a;
    return a; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo f = foo();
    std::cout << f.a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

works different on Mac(with `g++`) and VS2013. On Mac it prints `1`, whereas on Windows prints `2`. Then why doesn't the program call the copy constructor when `foo()` returns a class object by value?

Comment: Turn on optimizations with VS2013, and you'll see the same result you got with g++ (and neither result is wrong, as I'm sure an answer will make clear).

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to extra copy being elided in MAC. Probably, turning on optimizations in Visual studio would bring similar results.